# jQuery dynamic insert row for expand/collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have a table structure as follows;

```
    <tr>
    <td><div class="icon-chevron-right"></div></td>
    <td><div>List 1</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div class="icon-chevron-right"></div></td>
    <td><div>List 2</div></td>
    </tr>
```

Now on click of the icon image (chevron), I want the details row to be displayed immediately below the clicked row (It should be a tr containing child table). This should be inserted/appended dynamically on click of any of the list row.

How do I do this using jQuery? Any examples for reference would be really helpful..

Answer (score 0):

the following example creates a new `tr` (if does not exists) containing `table` element under the `tr` where the clicked icon exists.

```
function createChildTable(string)
{
    return $('<table>').append(
        $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').append(string)
        )
    );
}

$('.icon-chevron-right').click(function() {
   var details = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr.details');
   if (details.length) details.show();
   else {
    // first time clicked
    details = $('<tr>').append( createChildTable('child table details') ).addClass('details');
    $(this).closest('tr').after(details);
  }
});
```

[Example Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rKzkj/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there are two main ways to do this, and you'll have to figure out which one is best for you; it depends.

What you're talking about is ADDING a row into the DOM. This is fine in some cases, it depends on what this collapsed row is used for. If you want to be able to remove the collapsed row and add it again, it could make your life difficult if you have to reconstruct all the inner HTML via JavaScript every time.

```
var collapseHTML = '<tr class="collapse"><td colspan="2">This is my new row</td></tr>';    

$('.icon-chevron-right').click(function() {
    $('.collapse').remove(); // Deletes all rows that has class "collapse"
    collapseHTML.insertAfter( $(this).closest('tr') ); // Inserts what's stored in collapseHTML after "this closest tr"
});
```

Then, as someone else said, you can solve this by adding those rows from the get go like so:

```
<tr>
    <td><div class="icon-chevron-right"></div></td>
    <td><div>List 1</div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="collapse">
    <td colspan="2">This is my new row</td>
</tr>
```

Then, your css should loook something like this:

```
.collapse {
    display: none;
}

.collapse.active {
    display: block;
}
```

This means that when you add the `active` class to the collapse row, it goes from `display: none;` to `display: block;`. This you do via JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$('.icon-chevron-right').click(function() {
    $('.collapse.active').removeClass('active'); // Removes active from all active collapsed rows
    $(this).closest('tr').next().addClass('active'); // adds active class to "this closest tr's next element" (which is the collapse row)
});
```

Hope this helps!